# Как из переменной JQuery найти и удалить определенный блок. При этом не трогая другие блоки в этой-же переменной

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, node.js, socket.io

**Код на добавление блока в переменную:**

```
socket.on('add mess', function(data) {
            // Встраиваем полученное сообщение в блок с сообщениями
            // У блока с сообщением будет тот класс, который соответвует пользователю что его отправил
            $all_messages.append("<div class='alert alert-" + data.className + "'><b>" + data.name + "</b>: " + data.mess + "</div>");
        });
```

*Необходимо искать блок в переменной $all_messages по data.className, data.name, data.mess и удалять его. При этом не трогая другие блоки*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$all_messages.append("<div class='alert alert-" + data.className + "'><b>" +
  data.name + "</b>: <span>" + data.mess + "</span></div>");


$all_messages.find("div.alert.alert-" + data.className).each(function() {
  if ($(this).find("b").text() == data.name && $(this).find("span").text() == data.mess) {
    $(this).remove();
  }
});
```

Comment: спасибо большое тебе <3

Comment: @ДавидХакин Пожалуйста. Успехов. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.